# Access a global variable to track status in multiprocessing

Tags: python

I am writing a multiprocessing process that I want to monitor the status of.  How can I access my_var from thaht context?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

my_var = list()


def alter_my_var():
    global my_var
    for x in range(10):
        my_var.append(x)
        time.sleep(1)

p = Process(target=alter_my_var)
p.start()

while p.is_alive():
    print "Length of my_var is %i" % len(my_var)
    time.sleep(1)

p.join()

print "Done - final length of my_var is %s" % len(my_var)
```

Thanks

Comment: Processes aren't threads; the word "thread" is not applicable to this question.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, I'm sorry for the mis-wording.

Comment: @dmcmulle, Threads and Processes are two completely different things, what are you going to be actually doing in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `multiprocessing` not `threading`. Process run in a different memory space and variables get copied to the child process but they do not point to the same memory address anymore. Therefore, what you modify in the process can not be read by the main process.

If you don't care if it's a process or a thread try changing `Process` by `Thread` and it will work.

**Output**:

```
Length of my_var is 0
Length of my_var is 1
Length of my_var is 2
Length of my_var is 3
Length of my_var is 4
Length of my_var is 6
Length of my_var is 7
Length of my_var is 8
Length of my_var is 9
Length of my_var is 10
Done - final length of my_var is 10
```

**Edit**

As other people say, if you want to keep using a process you have to build some kind of IPC. You can use for that queues, the Manager, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  This is what I was looking for.  Cheers and thank you for the good explanation between the difference of process and thread.

Comment: Note that python threads use the same CPU than the main thread. If you want to do something CPU intensive inside the thread you should use Processes. If what you want to do is something simple, or I/O operations, threads are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [*Manager*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager), each process gets a copy of the list so you are not sharing one object, with *Manager().list()* you are:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import time

my_var = Manager().list()

def alter_my_var(my_var):
    for x in range(10):
        my_var.append(x)
        time.sleep(1)

p = Process(target=alter_my_var, args=(my_var, ))
p.start()
while p.is_alive():
    print "Length of my_var is %i" % len(my_var)
    time.sleep(1)
p.join()
print "Done - final length of my_var is %s" % len(my_var)
```

If we paste the code into Ipython, you can see the output:

```
## -- End pasted text --
Length of my_var is 0
Length of my_var is 1
Length of my_var is 3
Length of my_var is 4
Length of my_var is 5
Length of my_var is 6
Length of my_var is 7
Length of my_var is 8
Length of my_var is 9
Length of my_var is 10
Done - final length of my_var is 10
```

Comment: You probably still want to pass `my_var` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time

my_var = list()


def alter_my_var(my_var, conn):
    for x in range(10):
        my_var.append(x)
        conn.send(len(my_var))
        time.sleep(1)

global my_var
parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
p = Process(target=alter_my_var, args=(my_var,child_conn,))
p.start()

while p.is_alive():
    myvar_len = parent_conn.recv()
    print "Length of my_var is %i" % myvar_len       
    time.sleep(1)

p.join()

print "Done - final length of my_var is %s" % myvar_len
```